# Trying to create properties in a class then set their Value

Tags: javascript

I thought I got it right but the error says:

Failed tests:

> Should be a class with name, email, and password properties.
>   Expected undefined to be 'Dan'.

I looked on MDN and w3schools but apparently, I am just not understanding it. I know I am close though.

```
function ClassOne(name, pw, mail){
   /*Exercise One: In this exercise, you will be creating your own class!
   You are currently in the class, you are given three strings, name, pw, and mail.
   You need to create three properties on this class.
   Those properties are: 'username', 'password', and 'email'
   Set the value of username to name,
   Set the value of password to pw,
   Set the value of email to mail */
    }
  function User(username, password, email) {
      this.username = 'name';                 //<-------My Code
      this.password = 'pw';                   //<-------My Code
      this.email = 'mail';                    //<-------My Code
  }
 const dan = new User ('Dan', '123xyz', 'dan@aol.com');          //<-------My Code
```

Comment: The test seems to contradict the `/* Exercise One:*/` comment. Specifically, the comment says create a property named `username` but the test fails because there is no `name` property?

Comment: Additionally, whoever contrived this exercise doesn't really understand JavaScript as there is no class other than a key word that represents a constructor function such as the one you've written.

Comment: ```Expected undefined to be 'Dan'.```<br>
This strongly implies that it's not checking where you think it's checking.<br><br>
The example you showed should result in the error
```Expected 'name' to be 'Dan'.```<br>
because that's what you're setting username to be in your constructor.<br>
<br>
my guess is that your `const dan` isn't where you're supposed to store the instance.<br>
maybe you need to return `dan`?<br> The code posted by Tom Q. should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the properties equal to the arguments you're passing into the constructor. Right now you are passing values to the constructor, but not using them. Once inside the constructor you are setting your property values to literal strings. Try like this:

```js
function ClassOne(username, password, email) {
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
  this.email = email;
}
const dan = new ClassOne('Dan', '123xyz', 'dan@aol.com');

console.log(dan);
```

Comment: Yeah did it that way and still comes up with the same errors. Can't use class and a constructor until the next lesson. They want it the way you and I wrote it. This exercise is a little confusing.

Comment: After re-reading the comments in the code you posted I think the problem is that the name of the class is expected to be `ClassOne`. I don't see anywhere in the instructions that says to create a new class named `User` (even though that would make sense). I've updated my code - give that a shot.

Comment: Yes it was the classOne that did it. Thanks Tom!

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.username = name;
  this.password = pw;
  this.email = mail;
```

This is all you need for the solution.

Comment: You'll want to explain a bit more so that your answer is more robust.